# OWA dependant on Backup Domain Controller?

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-web-app

We have two domain controllers, HOST0 and HOST1. When HOST1 goes down, OWA is not available. When looking in exchange and running:

`Get-ClientAccessServer -Identity HOST0 | FL`

It shows HOST1 as the "Originating Server."

A) Why is OWA dependent on HOST1 when HOST0 is the Exchange Server?

B) Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Which of the DC's is the PDC emulator?

Comment: 1) I think you have a typo -> `When HOST1 goes down, OWA in available`  Seems like that should be "is" or "isn't," but I'm not sure which.  2) You have Exchange running on a domain controller?  Ouch.  Don't do that... time for an upgrade-migration to get it on its own box... or a good excuse to switch to hosted Exchange services.

Comment: I appologize, I should have specified; HOST0 is the PDC emulator.

Comment: Are both DC's Global Catalog servers?

Comment: Both DC's need to GC servers for it to function. Also, have both DC's been listed within DNS on the exchange server?

Comment: Yes, they are both Global Catalog servers.

Comment: Yes, there are A records for both hosts in DNS. 

For DNS servers on the NIC, HOST0 is looking at itself and HOST1.